# Show that if $g:I\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and differentiable then it is of class $C^1.$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $g: I\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and differentiable then it is of class $C^1.$ Here $I$ is an open interval.

The hint to the problem says that all functions $h:I \to \mathbb{R}$ that are increasing and verify the intermediate value theorem (IVT) is continuous. Therefore it suffices to show that $g'$ is increasing and verifies the  IVT. Clearly $g'$ is increasing because $g$ is convex. Then it is also mentioned that by using Darboux's theorem it can be said that $g'$ verifies the IVT.

I have two questions regarding this hint. First, why is the claim

> all functions $h:I \to \mathbb{R}$ that are increasing and verify the
>   intermediate value theorem (IVT) is continuous

true?

And second, Darboux's theorem works on closed intervals and so how can the author claim that it works for open intervals?